# Google Sheets Count

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to count the Yes in 2 columns if they are within a specific timeframe.  So if X is in Quarter 3, then I want to count the columns next to it if they are "Yes".

This is what I have right now but I am getting an error (I put the "then" in the formula here to make it easier to read, not in the actual formula)

```
=IF('Raw Data'!H:H, "Quarter 3 (July - September)" then COUNTIF('Raw Data'!J:J, "Yes") COUNTIF('Raw Data'!I:I, "Yes"))
```

Comment: Use `countifs` which supports multiple conditions.

Comment: @sandwich I tried that but it gives me a count of three because it is counting the quarter + the yes's. instead of just counting the yes's.

Comment: [`countifs`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en) requires all the listed conditions to hold. For example, `=countifs(A2:A, ">5", D2:D, "<3")` returns the number of rows where column A is >5 **and** columnd D is "<3"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=countifs('Raw Data'!H:H, "Quarter 3 (July - September)", 'Raw Data'!J:J, "Yes", 'Raw Data'!I:I, "Yes")
```

Comment: that only counted 1 yes but separated it out so it counts 2 now.  thanks

`=COUNTIFS('Raw Data'!H:H, "Quarter 2  (April - June)", 'Raw Data'!I:I, "Yes") + countifs('Raw Data'!H:H, "Quarter 2  (April - June)", 'Raw Data'!J:J, "Yes")`